# Alternatives to Visual Studio test runner for DNX and XUnit?

Tags: .net, tdd, dnx

The built-in test runner for Visual Studio 2015 is the only test runner I'm aware of that supports XUnit v2.x and DNX environment, and it is awful to work with.

I'm used to using TestDriven.NET for TDD activities. VS Test Runner lacks the relevant keyboard shortcuts, fails to output and XUnit information to the results, fails to identify tests half the time, is difficult to organize, etc. etc. It's terrible.

Are there any alternatives available yet?

UPDATE: https://github.com/xunit/resharper-xunit/issues/38 covers Resharper's progress towards supporting DNX environment.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit in version 3.2.0 supports.NET Core (Universal Windows Apps 10+, DNX Core 5+)

Comment: AH, I didn't realize NUnit is supported. However, XUnit seems to be the future of testing on the .NET platform, and it's what our project is using. Thanks for the heads-up!